# Execute a javascript function in Asynchronous mode

Tags: javascript

We have AJAX calls to hit a URL. Do we have option to run/execute JavaScript function in Asynchronous mode?

Note: setTimeout() will execute that function after some seconds but still that will execute in Synchronous mode.

Answer (score 4):

No. JavaScript runs in a single thread per page.

You want [HTML5 Web Workers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/). There's [a good introduction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) on HTML5 Rocks.

<strike>However, the Google Gears plugin provides a `WorkerPool`:</strike>

> **[WorkerPool API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_workerpool.html)**
>
> The WorkerPool API allows web applications to run JavaScript code in the background, without blocking the main page's script execution.

There's also [a proposal by the Gears team](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/HTML5WorkerProposal) to add this to HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

Most modern browsers implement JavaScript Web Workers, they provide a simple way to run scripts in background threads.

Check the following articles:

- [Computing with JavaScript Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/)
- [Using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers)
- [Web Worker Recommendation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/)
- [SHA-1 Computation using Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/apps/web-workers/) (demo)